# What is the fastest way to check if a word is in a 1mb word list?

Tags: android

I'm making a word game app that checks if a user's guess is a valid word by seeing if it exists in my word list. What would be the fastest way to check that? Should I make the list a database, a Collection... should I traverse it using binary search?

My current word list is txt file with one word per line.

Comment: I'll think either binary search or a hash table will be good, leaning more towards hash table.

Comment: Consider a trie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Look into suffix trees as well.